# Is this an okay way of doing a Django Rest Framework Serializer Update Method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I notice the DRF docs say you should pop each field off the validated_data dict in the update method as such:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.content = validated_data.get('content', instance.content)
    instance.created = validated_data.get('created', instance.created)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

However lets say you had a models with lots of fields. Would it not be easier to do something like the below? Or am I missing something?

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in instance.__dict__.iteritems():
            new_value = validated_data.get(attr, value)
            setattr(instance, attr, new_value)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Still learning Python so I'm not sure if I'm doing something unsafe or stupid here.

-- Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is not a model field then pop it. Otherwise just let it be in the validated_data dict.

for example:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    not_a_field = validated_data.pop('not_a_field', None)
    # do what you want here
    instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    # do what you want here
    return instance
```

We popped the non model fields so that we can call the super update method without any errors.